# degree of field extension / splitting field

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

i was wondering if anyone could give me a quick explanation about a problem concerning the degree of a field extension $Z\mid \mathbb{Q}$.  The problem is as follows :

Let $Z\subset \mathbb{C}$ be the splitting field of $f(X)=X^7-3$. Also let $\alpha = 3^{\frac{1}{7}}$ and $\zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{7}}$. Calculate $[Z : \mathbb{Q}]$.

I know the Polynomial $f$ to be irreducible because of Eisenstein (and also about the product rule for the degree of extension fields), but every time the field extension is slightly more complicated than simply adjoining the square root of a prime to $\mathbb{Q}$, i get confused because i cant simply say $[Z : \mathbb{Q}]=7$, because that would leave out the roots that have non zero imaginary parts(?). What exactly should my thought process be in these types of exercises?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The roots of your polynomial are $\;\alpha,\,\alpha\zeta,\ldots,\alpha\zeta^6\;$, yet observe that in fact $\;Z=\Bbb Q(\alpha,\,\zeta)\;$, and thus for its degree you can try

$$|Z:\Bbb Q|=\left|\Bbb Q(\alpha,\zeta):\Bbb Q(\zeta)\right|\,\left|\Bbb Q(\zeta):\Bbb Q\right|$$

Can you get it from here? Try to check stuff about irreducible polynomials and etc.

Comment: The problem is, i've had to deal with the "easy" field extensions so far, i.e adjoining $n$ many square roots of primes, etc. The part with the primitve roots of unity is what always throws me off, because i lack the intuition that i earlier had with the "easier" field extensions. Naively guessing would give me a degree of $7$ for Q(zeta) over Q, which is probably wrong.

Comment: Observe that of all the powers $\;\zeta^k\;$ , there is one that is real (and in fact ration), which is $\;\zeta^0=\zeta^7=1\;$ . The rest are complex non-real. We can see this also by decomposing $$z^7-1=(z-1)(z^6+...+z+1)$$ and this gives us $\;|\Bbb Q(\zeta):(\Bbb Q|=6 \;$, not $\;7\;$ ...This extension is very different from simply attaching square roots extensions.

Comment: So adjoining roots of unity in general has something to do with the cyclotomic polynomials?

Comment: @bsvgu Indeed it does: the cyclotomic polynomial of the corresponding roots of unity is the minimal polynomial of any of the generators of the group of roots of unity. Here, $\;\zeta,...,\zeta^6\;$ are all of them (separatedly, of course) generators of the cyclic group of roots of unity of order $\;\phi(7)=6\;$ , and that is the extension's degree, too.

Comment: I see, that helped a lot, thanks. :)